# Spring Security denies logout CSRF token

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to implement an Angular app using this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Logging in works and performing subsequent HTTP calls works, too. Angular successfully appends the CSRF token and Spring successfully parses it. Assuming the token is `foo`, the requests will contain these headers:

> Cookie: `JSESSIONID=...; XSRF-TOKEN=foo`
>
> X-XSRF-TOKEN: `foo`

Now, when trying to log out with
`$http.post('logout', {})`, Angular will use exactly the same headers. However, Spring answers with a 403:

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

This is what my security configuration looks like:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .logout().and()
        .addFilterBefore(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

CsrfHeaderFilter is the class [explained in the tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_csrf_protection) (which apparently works for every other request).

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's 2 months late, but I was following the exact same guide today and this unanswered post keeps on popping up so here's the solution.

Basically, you were missing the `csrfTokenRepository()` configuration in the `HttpSecurity` configurer.

Spring `CsrfTokenRepository` expects the header `"X-CSRF-TOKEN"` but Angular sends the token in a header called `"X-XSRF-TOKEN"` so [the guide](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) recommended you setup an instance of `CsrfTokenRepository` which expects the Angular default header `"X-XSRF-TOKEN"`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .logout()
        .and()
        //This is the first part you were missing
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}


@Bean
public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository(){
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();

    // This is the second part you were missing
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```