# Spring Security - Invalid CSRF token at /logout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, csrf

I have an app that uses Thymeleaf templates and Spring Boot configuration. I am having a Invalid CSRF token problem meanwhile using some of the endpoints. App stores a CSRF token at cookies.

At one of the templates, where the logout button is, when I do not include any links (stylesheet) and scripts (JS) at , everything is working well. But when I include any  or  headers, I have a "Invalid CSRF token for localhost:/logout" problem.

Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
//              .disable()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/dashboard")
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                    .addFilterBefore(customFilter(), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**")
                .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/home",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/logon","/login/**", "/oauth2_register/**","/register/**")
                    .anonymous()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                .disable()
                    .logout()
                .deleteCookies("access_token")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                    .authorizationRequestResolver(customAuthorizationRequestResolver())
                .and()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler());
    }


}
```

index.html where I use the default "/logout" endpoint provided by Spring Security:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="'Welcome '+${user.getUsername()}+'!'"></title>

<!-- When I include the part with Bootstrap, an Invalid CSRF token error is thrown at Spring -->
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css"/>-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/font-awesome/css/all.css"/>-->


    <!--<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="/webjars/popper.js/popper.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script th:src="@{js/fade.js}"></script>-->

    <!--Bootstrap-->
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="backend-validation-alert" th:if="${errorMessage}">
            <span th:text="${errorMessage}"></span>
            <script>fade();</script>
        </div>
    </div>
        <h1 th:text="'Welcome '+${user.getUsername()}+'!'"></h1>

        <form role="form" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
            <div><input type="submit" value="Log out"/></div>
        </form>

        <form role="form" th:action="@{/user/settings/delete}" method="POST">
            <div><input type="submit" value="Delete account"/></div>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debugged the code and checked CsrfFilter, I see that a different hidden _csrf parameters are created at the Thymeleaf template for the POST forms, which doesn't matches the CSRF at the cookie and an exception is thrown. Filter is taking the right XSRF-TOKEN value as the token to be validated, but the CSRF token stored as a parameter in the request is wrong and different.

Did anyone experienced a similar problem? When exactly a new CSRF token should be generated? Because in my case, when I check the network information, I see that a new CSRF token is generated for every single resource (.js, .css, .html) after login, but only the .html CSRF token is stored as hidden parameter at Thymeleaf, which results in Invalid CSRF token error.

Additional note: I have observed that first the initial html is being loaded and correct CSRF form parameters are both set at HTML hidden inputs and as a cookie. But then, JS and CSS and other files are going into CSRF authentication and resulting in changing of cookie CSRF token. I guess solution will include somehow excluding these header scripts and links from authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756460/spring-security-denies-logout-csrf-token

Comment: @MebinJoe nope, I already have tokenrepository configured at the security configurations and header names are already added.

Comment: Try adding the CSRF token into your logout form, _<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />_

Comment: When I check the generated HTML, I can already see a _csrf parameter generated. But it is different than the one we are expecting, because the stored _csrf values are generated just after the .html is generated. But after that, the CSRF cookie changes 5 times because of the other resources loading. What Spring does is to compare the cookie and the parameter value, which eventually fails. I wonder if I am missing some configuration... I tried this solution and the same _csrf value is generated again at HTML.